# How do I stack two formpanels?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've got two formpanels I need to stack vertically. When I put both in a panel with layout 'fit', they render on top of each other. If I use a VBox, flex:1 on both splits them by percentage, when I need one form after the other. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put any layout and they will fit themselves automatically. By default, a container has AutoContainerLayout. Add vertical scrolling only to the parent container